# Send hebrew filename in header as content disposition to AngularJS client

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I need to send filename (in hebrew) to a client in AngularJS. In my web api method, I use following code to send content disposition header:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.Charset = "UTF-8";
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

//simplified - actually sending a variable with filename
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=דיזינגוף.xlsx");

using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
  wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
  MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
  Response.Flush();
  Response.End();
}
```

But when I look at console in browser (Chrome),I see 
 [image]

How can I send/read the UTF-8 file name in my client application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope it will helps others:

We need to encode the filename containing utf characters. You can do that before adding the response header:

```
//filename - 2100871-2_החל_25042019.xlsx
var file = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(filename, Encoding.UTF8);
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + file + ".xlsx");
```

Then on client side, we need to decode it using

```
  var filename;

  var disposition = headers['content-disposition'];

  if (disposition && disposition.indexOf('attachment') !== -1) {
      var filenameRegex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;
      var matches = filenameRegex.exec(disposition);

      if (matches != null && matches[1]) {
          filename = matches[1];
      }
 }
 filename = decodeURIComponent(filename); //decode here
```